# How to allow only assignee to merge pull request in github?

Tags: github

I would like to know how to allow only assignee to merge pull request in github but not participants.

Comment: Your approach goes against scm usage best practices. The person who's assigned an issue / task should never be the one merging its work. Indeed prior to merging a review should be done and this review should be done by a different person from the one having written the code to be merged.

Comment: Kraal, Thanks for the comments. I think, you misunderstood my question. I am not referring to the person who raised the pull request as assignee.  I am referring to the person to whom the pull request is assigned for review. When a pull request is raised everybody who has push access will receive notification of the pull request and they can merge the pull request too. But I want only the assignee to merge the pull request but nobody else.   Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @Uday Did you find the way to do this?